# How high do I need to go to take a picture that covers a specific area?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let's say I have a terrain that I want to take a picture.

The terrain is about 1.5 kilometers by 5 kilometers

My camera has a FOV of approx 90º, taking pictures in 4:3

How do I calculate how high would I need to go to take a picture to get the desired parts of this terrain? What is the formula behind this?

I wanted to know how to compute this, because my values will change in the near future, to higher and lower dimensions.

Thanks

Comment: I feel that I'm missing some of the arguments, or that the provided information may not be enough. If so, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the aspect ratio is $4:3$ you will need to image an area $5 \times 3.75$ km to get the area you want.  The diagonal is then $6.25$ km.  If you draw a triangle with the camera on one corner and the diagonal of the image area on the opposite side, the angle at your camera is $90^\circ$.  If you now drop a perpendicular from the camera to the opposite side, you get a right triangle with the right angle at the center of the side on the ground.  The length on the ground is $3.125$ km and it is a $90-45-45$ triangle, so you need to be $3.125$ km high.  If your camera field of view were $\theta$, the half diagonal of the image is $L$, and the height is $h$ you have $\tan \frac \theta 2 = \frac Lh$

Comment: Thanks very much for showing the complete answer. This will greatly help my calculations!

Comment: Just as clarification, the formula would be tan( FOV / 2 ) = ( L / h ), with L = (sqrt(a² + b²))/2, can you confirm this @Ross Millikan ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.